# How to use image OCR for videos?

Tags: python, ocr, yolo, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Currently I am working on automatic number plate recognition system. I have used yolov7 for number plate detection and Text detection facility from Google vision API. I have tested the whole system with test images. Now I am willing to develop the system to detect and read number plates in video sources. I could do the detection part for the video and where I am stuck is using the OCR for the detected bound box in the video.

For images, I first apply the trained YOLOv7 model and extract the number plate and save the detected number plate as a cropped part from the original image in the directory. And then the OCR is applied for that cropped part(Number Plate) and the text is read.

Test Sample:
[image]
NP detection:
[image]
Detected NP: (OCR is applied to this cropped image)
[image]
Detected Text:
[image]

I could detect the number plates from the videos but could not find a way to freeze the frame where a number plate is detected and apply ocr or any other way to read the number plate.

Is there a way to achieve this? any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the coordinates of the bounding box from each frame where the bounding box is appeared and apply OCR.